# Calling another Gem as a program from my Gem

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, rubygems

I'm working on a command line tool (a ruby gem) to quickly and easily generate custom jekyll repositories from some basic user input for my company. I would like to add a feature where the gem can automatically build the repo and output the finished directory, but the `jekyll` gem doesn't seem to provide any internal ruby interface to do that, at least not one that would be easy to implement.

Is there a way I could have my gem call their gem as a program, i.e. `system 'jekyll build'`, but without having to worry about whether or not the user has the `jekyll` gem installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `jekyll` to your gems list of dependencies, by adding the following to your gem's `.gemspec` file. That means whenever someone installs your gem, `jekyll` would also be installed.

```
spec.add_dependency 'jekyll'
```

Comment: So there's no need to call the gem in any special way?

Comment: I just tried it on a machine with `jekyll` uninstalled and it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Was there an error? Was the Gem not installed? Were you unable to call the installed gem?

Comment: My mistake. I installed my gem, then I uninstalled `jekyll` and I got an error that jekyll was not installed. When I tried it again, first uninstalling `jekyll` then installing my gem, it worked.